# Send back file buffer without await

Tags: typescript, api, sharepoint, download, nestjs

I want my NestJS application to have an endpoint to download a file from Sharepoint API.
I've already done that, but it's downloading the file in a Buffer, and after it has been downloaded, it send it back to client who runs endpoint.

For the moment my code is like this :

```
private async sharepointApi(url: string): Promise<Response> {
    // Get authentificated
    const authHeaders = await this.getAuthHeaders();

    // If authentification failed, return undefined
    if (authHeaders === undefined) {
      console.error('Error while getting conntected');
      return undefined;
    }

    // Get api result
    return fetch(`${this.site.url}/_api/${url}`, {
      headers: {
        ...authHeaders,
        Accept: 'application/json;odata=verbose',
      },
    });
  }

private async sharepointBufferApi(url: string): Promise<Buffer> {
    const result = await this.sharepointApi(url);
    return result.buffer();
}

async getFile(fileRelativeUrl = ''): Promise<Buffer> {
    fileRelativeUrl = this.transformServerRelativeUrl(fileRelativeUrl);
    // Get file as a Buffer from Sharepoint
    const spFile = this.sharepointBufferApi(
        `web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('${encodeURIComponent(
            fileRelativeUrl,
        )}')/$value`,
    );

    return spFile;
}
```

So this code, await for my NestJS app to download the file.
Only when it's downloaded, it sends it back to client.
I wonder if it's possible to send it "live" without await download.
Because for a sample file of 700Mb, i takes a while before i start download it when i hit endpoint to download...

Thanks in advance for any responses !

Answer (score 1):

Good day!

You need to use Streams. Take a look at the [official NestJS documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/streaming-files).

Since you are not reading the file from the `fs` you need to convert `Buffer` to readable stream:

```
const { Readable } = require('stream');
const stream = Readable.from(buffer);
```

then you can do:

```
stream.pipe(res);
```

This approach will allow you to stream massive files without overloading the system.

If you want to know more about the Streams in NodeJS, check out [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BdePYKgrMh0)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response !

This is what i have in my controller.
I await the buffer from the fetch, and then stream pipe in the response.
But i wanted to know if there is another solution then awaiting the buffer.
Because for a big file, i have to await the file from Sharepoint API, and after that it is downloaded in the Buffer, i can stream in the response, and takes some time..